# Golang Unmarshal slice of slice of ints

Tags: json, go, struct

How do you unmarshal a JSON into a slice of slices of ints? I keep on getting a blank struct:
[https://play.golang.org/p/Hgnh5C9FN_](https://play.golang.org/p/Ch4k4BH_9C)

Also is it possible to unmarshal something like [[1 2][3 4]] without a key e.g. {"key":[[1 2][3 4]]}?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems there is a three issues in your provided code snippet.

- Struct field have to be exported, refer to [Exported vs Unexported](https://www.goinggo.net/2014/03/exportedunexported-identifiers-in-go.html) identifiers
- Your JSON data is invalid `invalid character '[' after array element {[]}`
- Field data type definition

I have updated your code here https://play.golang.org/p/zX7KEPKB8H

Output `{[[1 2] [3 4]]}`